# When I start my instance with encrypted volumes attached, the instance immediately stops with the error "client error on launch"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, client, launch

When I was start EC2 instance with encrypted volumes attached from lambda function which was invoked from cloudwatch event, the instance immediately stops with the error "client error on launch". Can anyone help me in this.?

It's related with AWS KMS permission.

Answer (score 1):

It is related to the permissions.

Please check if user/role has required permissions for KMS or if there is any specific restriction applied for KMS key usage.

I have found a great post regarding this: [Instance with encrypted volumes attached stops immediately when started](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/encrypted-volumes-stops-immediately/)